# Need help with my on collision restart program

Tags: unity, c#

I tried using the program

```
using UnityEngine;

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "setting_object_tag")
    {
        Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
    }  
}
```

But the `OnTriggerEnter` command came up with an error saying "a namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods".

And the `Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);` program had an error saying "application.loadedLevel is obsolete, use sceneManager to determine what scenes have been loaded".

Answer (score 3):

The C# programming language requires that every method is wrapped in a class. In order to add such a class as a behaviour to a Unity game object, it needs to be a class which inherits from `MonoBehaviour`. Your script file should look like this:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class RestartOnCollision : MonoBehaviour 
{

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "setting_object_tag")
        {
            Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
        }  
    }
}
```

Note that a script file needs to be named like the class it contains. So in this case, the script should be saved as `RestartOnCollision.cs`.

Regarding the second message: "application.loadedLevel is obsolete, use sceneManager to determine what scenes have been loaded": This is just a warning, not an error. `Application.LoadLevel` still works as you would expect it. However, in a new project you should use [`SceneManager.LoadScene`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html) instead.

By the way `setting_object_tag` is a really strange tag name. Did you add a tag with that name to the player (or whatever object you want to cause a level restart if it enters this trigger)?

Comment: Thanks,  setting_object_tag isn't actually my object name I just changed it to it's real name but the reason for it being that is because I found this program online and that was the name of it. But now I have no errors in the script but their are errors in the console I have the referenced script (unknown) on this behavior is missing!

Comment: Sorry didn't mean to post that yet. But my other errors are

Comment: Oops did it again lol my other errors are referenced script on this behavior (game Object 'new sprite') is missing! The referenced script (unknown) on this behavior is missing! The referenced script on this behavior (game Object 'main camera') is missing! The referenced script (RestartOnCollision.) Is missing! referenced script on this behavior (game object 'player') is missing!

Comment: @TheDragonBorn113 It sounds like you assigned a script file to various game objects and then renamed or moved the file. Just remove the broken behaviour in the inspector and assign it again.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help but I'm not quite sure what you mean I double checked what I was making in the quotation marks and it should all be right but I still have all the errors in the console.